# How can I create a column that accepts only three types of data?

Tags: validation, openoffice-calc

I would like to create a column in a spreadsheet that accepts only three values (`regular`, `extra` and `remote`).

How can I accomplish this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to Data > Validity > allows List and write your items. You can specify error message and so on.

Once you do it for a cell, copy, select all the cells you want to apply this format to, and paste special > format.